# MySQL select from two concatenated strings not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select the data from a table called t32 with the following code:

```
SELECT
  timestamp AS "time",
  id
FROM CONCAT('t', "32")
```

However the following error appears:

```
#1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch nachschlagen bei '("t", "32") LIMIT 0, 25' in Zeile 4
```

free translation to english:

```
#1064 - Error in SQL syntax. Please look up the correct syntax near '("t", "32") LIMIT 0, 25' in line 4
```

However if I use

```
SELECT timestamp AS "time", id FROM t32
```

everything works like expected.

about help i would be very happy

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server? Your title says MySQL but your are tagging SQL Server...

Comment: In your question title you wrote MySql but you have tagged question with sql-server. Kindly correct the mistake.

Comment: You need _dynamic SQL_ here. i.e. first build up the SQL statement, then prepare and execute.

Comment: BTW, t32 is a name that indicates you have t1, t2, t3 etc. How come you have so many numbered tables?

Comment: #1064 is a MySQL error. Plus, the original error message includes a `LIMIT` clause in the query, which is MySQL syntax, not SQL Server. @a_horse_with_no_name beat me to fixing the tags.

Comment: thank you for your replies. It's MySql, sorry for choosing the wrong tag.
@jarlh thank you for the suggestion, I will try it

Comment: @jarlh I have that many tables because I want to track the price of multiple object. It's the easiest solution I found to create a new table for every product, but I'm open to better solutions.

Comment: The general solution is to store all products in the same table. Just add a "product" column.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I changed the structure of the data like you described it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to construct a table name in a SQL query.  You cannot do this with a regular SQL query.

One solution is dynamic SQL -- that is a `prepare` and `exec` approach.

However, this really suggests a problem with your data model.  In general, constructing table names should not be necessary.  All data about a single entity should be in a single table.

So, the query should look more like:

```
select t.*
from t
where <somecol> = 32;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. As you and some others suggested, I changed the structure of the data model. Thank you for this advice